# What's for dinner?

Tags: visual

Four-star chef and puzzling enthusiast Pat Ravioli is known for her creativity in the kitchen. This morning, Pat gave her assistant a shopping list:
$\newcommand{q}[1]{{\huge\text{#1}}}$$\newcommand{a}[1]{{\LARGE \text{#1}}}$$\newcommand{z}[1]{{\small \text{#1}}}$$\newcommand{w}[1]{{\huge \mathbb{#1}}}$$\newcommand{s}[1]{{\LARGE \mathbb{#1}}}$$\newcommand{x}[1]{{\small\mathbb{#1}}}$

- $\z{P}\x{E}\s{P}\a{P}\q{E}\w{R}$
- $\w{S}\q{A}\z{L}\x{T}$
- $\z{F}\q{L}\w{O}\x{U}\z{R}$
- $\w{M}\x{A}\q{Y}\z{O}$
- $\x{O}\z{R}\a{A}\s{N}\a{G}\q{E}\w{S}$
- $\w{A}\q{P}\a{P}\s{L}\x{E}\z{S}$

What is Pat planning to make?

Comment: Do the names of the LaTeX commands have anything to do with the puzzle, or is the source code irrelevant?

Comment: The source code is irrelevant

Comment: So nice! How comes the nicest puzzles are solved before I even get a first look?

Comment: Amazing puzzle!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

She is planning to make

> SCONES

---

I'll give a series of hints that lead up to the solution.

Hint 1:

> Only the fonts matter. The words and their contained letters are purely thematic. They could be replaced with any words of the same length.

Hint 2:

> Each letter comes in three different sizes and two different weights (normal and blackboard).

Hint 3:

> Each font can be described by a cell on a 3x2 grid.

Hint 4:

> There's many possible orientations for the grid, but what's the most natural convention for graphing size and for graphing thickness?

Hint 5:

> Right, it's increasing height on the Y axis, and increasing thickness (normal then blackboard) on the X axis.

Hint 6:

> So, the letters in each word correspond to a sequence of points on this 3x2 grid. What do we do with them?

Hint 7:

> Right, we "connect the dots" in order to get letters. They look like [the LCD digital letters](http://luc.devroye.org/led.html) (except the slant of the N connects top left to bottom right).[image]

And this gives the answer:

> SCONES. Or, if you oriented the grid differently, you recognize that you can reorient it to get that.